# ios how to access to a node inside of json structure from nsmutabledictionary

Tags: ios, json

I'm serializing a JSON file into nsmutabledictonary. The JSON file has this format:

```
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "value": "Files",
        "menuoffiles": {
            "menuitem": [
                {
                    "value": "New",
                    "date": "03162011"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Open",
                    "date": "03162012"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Close",
                    "date": "03162014"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My question is from the nsmutabledictionary how can I access the values of the keys of "open" or "close" ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. By the way: `dictionary[@"menuoffiles][1][@"value"]`.

Comment: @H2CO3: I think he need only for open & close, so for the last `key` he has to use loop and if-else. :p

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Marginal.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (you can't do it in a single step as you can't index into the array at the same time as the dictionary):

```
NSArray *menuItems = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"menu.menuoffiles.menuitem"];
```

Now you can iterate:

```
for (NSDictionary *menuItem in menuItems) {
    if ([[menuItem objectForKey:@"value"] isEqualToString:@"Open"]]) {
        //...
    }
}
```

or filter:

```
NSArray *openTimes = [menuItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value == %@", @"Open"]];
```

Depending on what you're going to use the result for.

Comment: Note that (as H2CO3 points out) you can now use [dictionary style subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#dictionary-style-subscripting) to make this code more readable.

Comment: @RussellZahniser, true, but it makes additional assumptions about the order of the array. And valueForKeyPath wouldn't be shortened so its a trade off.

Comment: OMG I have been trying to figure this out for days! This example worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to figure something like this out is to just use NSLog to print out what the format of the dictionary looks like. Anyway, you should be able to access top level objects through objectForKey, and then objects on inside levels through objectForKey or by iterating through them if it is an array not a dictionary.